# Error with the for loop code. The loop is not overwriting the values in the cloumn

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I want to add a new column consisting different colors to my data frame. So that I can use that column in the arg `col` while plotting the points of that variable.

I want to assign same color for a values falling in same range and different colors for those falling in different range.

For example, I have a certain dataset consisting of following values:

```
> CN 

A    X
1    0.05
2    0.09
3    NA
4    0.12
5    0.35
6    0.21
7    NA
8    0.01
9    0.14
10   0.32
11   0.43
12   0.19
```

I would like to add a separate column (Col) to my dataframe `CN`

```
> CN$Col <= "white"
```

Its a success in creating a new column. I would like to assign different colors to each of these values. And assign either `white` or a transparent color for `NA` values. 
i.e

```
<0.05      -- red
0.05 - 0.1 -- orange
0.1  - 0.2 -- yellow
0.2  - 0.3 -- green
0.3  - 0.4 -- darkviolet
0.4  - 0.5 -- blue
```

Here is the code I have written

```
CN$Col <- "white"

for (i in 1:length(CN)) {
d <- is.na(CN$X[i])
 if (d == "FALSE") {
   if (CN$X[i] <= 0.05)
     CN$Col[i] <- "red"
   else if (CN$X[i] <= 0.1 && CN$X[i] > 0.05)
     CN$Col[i] <- "orange"
   else if (CN$X[i] <= 0.2 && CN$X[i] > 0.1)
     CN$Col[i] <- "yellow"
   else if (CN$X[i] <= 0.3 && CN$X[i] > 0.2)
     CN$Col[i] <- "green"
   else if (CN$X[i] <= 0.4 && CN$X[i] > 0.3)
     CN$Col[i] <- "darkviolet"
   else if (CN$X[i] <= 0.5 && CN$X[i] > 0.4)
     CN$Col[i] <- "blue"
 }
else
CN$Col[i] <- rgb(0, 0 , 0, alpha = 0) # rgb command can be replaced with color white
}
```

This code does not overwrite the white I have fed to the column earlier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or you could use the function `cut`.

Comment: You can simply use `cut`, something among these lines (maube will need so tweaking) `cut(CN$X, breaks = c(-Inf, 0.05, .1, .2, .3 , .4, .5), labels = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "darkviolet", "blue"))`

Comment: It also looks like a good case for using `switch`.

Comment: `x <- c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "darkviolet", "blue")[findInterval(CN$X, c(0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4))];replace(x, is.na(x), rgb(0, 0 , 0, alpha = 0))`

Comment: also, `for(i in 1:nrow(CN))`

Answer (score 0):

this should do it!

```
for (i in 1:length(CN[,2])) {
  d <- is.na(CN$X[i])
  if (d == "FALSE") {
    if (CN$X[i] <= 0.05)
      CN$Col[i] = "red"
    else if (CN$X[i] <= 0.1 && CN$X[i] > 0.05)
      CN$Col[i] = "orange"
    else if (CN$X[i] <= 0.2 && CN$X[i] > 0.1)
      CN$Col[i] = "yellow"
    else if (CN$X[i] <= 0.3 && CN$X[i] > 0.2)
      CN$Col[i] = "green"
    else if (CN$X[i] <= 0.4 && CN$X[i] > 0.3)
      CN$Col[i] = "darkviolet"
    else if (CN$X[i] <= 0.5 && CN$X[i] > 0.4)
      CN$Col[i] = "blue"
  }
  else
    CN$Col[i] <- rgb(0, 0 , 0, alpha = 0) # rgb command can be replaced with color white
}
```

The length you define is only 3 not 12.

```
CN$Col[i] <= "orange"
```

Also in this line is a mistake. It should be:

```
CN$Col[i] = "orange"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why not just use `cut`? Not to mention this was mentioned in comments a while ago.

Comment: I do not know the `cut` function. I just read the question and I gave an answer. That's it...